# Outputting a randomized array to a file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, printwriter

I'm trying to write a program that takes an array of 200 numbers (1-200), randomizes them, and then outputs those numbers to a text file.

I've been struggling for the whole day and I can't figure out why nothing is working.

Main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    int[] numbers= new int [201];

    for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=i;

    }
}//end main method
```

Randomize method:

```
public static int[] randomizeArray(int[] numbers) 
{
    Random gen= new Random(10);

    for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        int n= gen.nextInt(200);
        numbers[i]=n;
    }

    return numbers;

}//end randomizeArray method
```

And the print method:

```
public static int[] outputArray(int[] numbers) throws IOException
{

    FileOutputStream output;

    output= new FileOutputStream("RandomOut.txt");

    new PrintStream(output).println(randomizeArray(numbers));

    output.close();

    return numbers;

}//end method outputArray
```

Any help would be great, I know I'm overlooking something or doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I do not know.. it compiles fine but nothing is outputted. I can't find the problem :/

Comment: Post the error message your getting. Or let us know whats not working

Comment: One thing, `int[] numbers = new int[201];` creates an array with 201 numbers in it. Also, if this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: May be you need to print `Arrays.deepToString(numbers)`.

Comment: I know, that was an accident. and sorry, just tagged it.

Comment: which parts don't work as planned?

Comment: You do know that your main method is not calling outputArray right?

Comment: It's not calling none of his methods.

Comment: @VilasJagannath That, and it's not calling the randomize function either.

Comment: @izuriel outputArray calls randomizeArray.

Comment: @VilasJagannath Hah, missed that. Good call then :p

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you call outputArray at the end of your main method?

Comment: @Jake223 outputArray calls randomizeArray

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is the line:

```
new PrintStream(output).println(randomizeArray(numbers));
```

This will probably print something like:

```
[I@10769dd
```

yes? You need to write a for loop to output the numbers, something like:

```
for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    new PrintStream(output).println(numbers[i]);
}
```

except that you don't want to create the PrintStream each time in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to use `Arrays.toString(int[] arr)` to print that array.

2) if you mean to reorder the array input, that requires code tht is very diferent. 
otherwise, get rid of the input and use a new array.

3) call your helper methods!

EDIT: added this psuedocode:

```
boolean[] used=new boolean[200];
make old[] and new[]
for(i=0;i<200;i++){
    int n=random number from 0 to 199;
    while(used[n]) n=(n+1)%200;
    new[i]=old[n];
    used[n]=true;
}
return new;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main method initializes an array of 201 elements (instead of 200), and doesn't do anything with this array. So obviously, there is no randomization and now writing to any file. The main method should call `randomizeArray` and then `outputArray`.

The initialization of the array elements in main is useless, since the elements will be reinitialized by the `randomizeArray` method. This method, by the way, doesn't need to return anything.

Finally, the `outputArray` method should loop through the array and println each element. The stream should be closed in a finally block. It should not return anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't resist...

```
    String filename = "random200.txt";
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 201; i++)
    {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (!numbers.isEmpty())
    {
        int position = new SecureRandom().nextInt(numbers.size());
        Integer randomNumber = numbers.remove(position);
        sb.append(randomNumber + "\n");
    }
    try
    {
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF8"));
        out.append(sb.toString());
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```